# whereHas filter query issue on laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8

hello guys i want result like i have many products and in products have many supplier and one customer so when i search product description than display all product but i want output like product display but match with customer id

```
$pi = Product::where('customer_id',$customerId)
            ->whereHas('supplier', function (Builder $query) use($search) {
                    $query->where('sys_state', '!=', '-1')
                    ->orWhere('name','LIKE','%' . $search . '%');
            })
            ->where('sys_state','!=','-1')
            ->orWhere('prd_our_item_no', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('prd_supplier_item', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('prd_description','LIKE','%' . $search . '%')
            ->get();
```

i try this query but all the product display when i search customer id where condition not work

Answer (score 0):

i try to wrap orwhere but noting can search on it

```
$pi = Product::where('customer_id', $customerId)
        ->where('sys_state', '!=', '-1')
        ->whereHas('supplier', function (Builder $query) use ($search) {
            $query->where('sys_state', '!=', '-1')
            ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($search) {
                $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->where('sys_state','!=','-1');
            });
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($search, $customerId) {
            $query->where('prd_description', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->where('sys_state', '!=', '-1')
            ->where('customer_id',$customerId);
        })
        ->orWhere(function($query) use($search, $customerId){
            $query->where('prd_supplier_item', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->where('sys_state', '!=', '-1')
            ->where('customer_id',$customerId);
        })
        ->orWhere(function($query) use($search, $customerId){
            $query->where('prd_our_item_no', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->where('sys_state', '!=', '-1')
            ->where('customer_id',$customerId);
        })
    ->get();
```

Comment: Hi, if this is an update to your question, add it there. You can edit your question. Here it will be lost.